# How to make Flutter ListView to add extra empty widget

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a listview with data from my JSON API which works perfectly but I have a scenario I will like to work around, it is basically payment progress that is meant to show a list of paid users and add to the list dummy widget to the list indicating the number of users left to pay. Below API returns information about users and the number of users left to pay but I can't find how to add a dummy widget to the list view to show the number of users left.

```
var numberOfUserLeft;
List data;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    isLoadingActivity = true;
    String url;

     url = "mylink.php";


    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(url),
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    );

    this.setState(() {
      data = json.decode(response.body);
      isLoadingActivity = false;
      numberOfUserLeft = data[0]['userCount']

    });

     return "Success!";
  }

// my listview below

ListView.builder(
                     scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                     // padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                     itemCount: data == null
                         ? 0
                         : data.length,
                     itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                       return       Container(
                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                           child: Row(children: [


                             Container(
                               padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                               child: Stack(
                                 clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                                 children: [
                                   CircleAvatar(
                                       radius: 60,
                                       backgroundColor: colorGreen,

                                       child:Container(
                                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                           margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                             color: Colors.white,
                                             shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                           ),
                                           child: ClipOval(
                                             child: Container(
                                               height: 250,
                                               width: 250,
                                               child: data[position]["profile_img"]!=null?Image.network(
                                                 data[position]["profile_img"],
                                                 fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                               ):Image.asset("assets/person_icon.png"),
                                             ),
                                           )
                                       )),
                                   Positioned(
                                     bottom: 100,
                                     right: 45,
                                     child: InkWell(
                                       onTap: () {},
                                       child:  Center(
                                         child: CircleAvatar(
                                           backgroundColor: colorGreen,
                                           radius: 15.0,
                                           child: Icon(
                                             Icons.check,
                                             color: Colors.white,
                                             size: 25,
                                           ),
                                         ),
                                       ),
                                     ),
                                   ),

                                 ],
                               ),
                             ),
                             Container(
                               padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                               child: Stack(
                                 clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                                 children: [
                                   CircleAvatar(
                                       radius: 60,
                                       backgroundColor: colorGreen,

                                       child:Container(
                                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                           margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                             color: Colors.white,
                                             shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                           ),
                                           child: ClipOval(
                                             child: Container(
                                               height: 250,
                                               width: 250,
                                               child: data[position]["profile_img"]!=null?Image.network(
                                                 data[position]["profile_img"],
                                                 fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                               ):Image.asset("assets/person_icon.png"),
                                             ),
                                           )
                                       )),
                                   Positioned(
                                     bottom: 100,
                                     right: 45,
                                     child: InkWell(
                                       onTap: () {},
                                       child:  Center(
                                         child: CircleAvatar(
                                           backgroundColor: colorGreen,
                                           radius: 15.0,
                                           child: Icon(
                                             Icons.check,
                                             color: Colors.white,
                                             size: 25,
                                           ),
                                         ),
                                       ),
                                     ),
                                   ),

                                 ],
                               ),
                             ),
                           ],))
                       ;
                     })
```

The above API returns only one user to have paid ow can I use `numberOfUserLeft` to create a dummy widget in Listview, Find the attached screenshot of what I'm looking at:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So in your `itemBuilder:` add an `if-else` statement like this

```
if(data.length >0){ //this means that it will never be less than 1
  data.insert(1,"instances of what you want to add");
 return Container(
                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                           child: Row(children: [


                             Container(
                               padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                               child: Stack(
                                 clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                                 children: [
                                   CircleAvatar(
                                       radius: 60,
                                       backgroundColor: colorGreen,

                                       child:Container(
                                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                           margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                             color: Colors.white,
                                             shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                           ),
                                           child: ClipOval(
                                             child: Container(
                                               height: 250,
                                               width: 250,
                                               child: data[position]["profile_img"]!=null?Image.network(
                                                 data[position]["profile_img"],
                                                 fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                               ):Image.asset("assets/person_icon.png"),
                                             ),
                                           )
                                       )),
                                   Positioned(
                                     bottom: 100,
                                     right: 45,
                                     child: InkWell(
                                       onTap: () {},
                                       child:  Center(
                                         child: CircleAvatar(
                                           backgroundColor: colorGreen,
                                           radius: 15.0,
                                           child: Icon(
                                             Icons.check,
                                             color: Colors.white,
                                             size: 25,
                                           ),
                                         ),
                                       ),
                                     ),
                                   ),

                                 ],
                               ),
                             ),
                             Container(
                               padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                               child: Stack(
                                 clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                                 children: [
                                   CircleAvatar(
                                       radius: 60,
                                       backgroundColor: colorGreen,

                                       child:Container(
                                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                           margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                             color: Colors.white,
                                             shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                           ),
                                           child: ClipOval(
                                             child: Container(
                                               height: 250,
                                               width: 250,
                                               child: data[position]["profile_img"]!=null?Image.network(
                                                 data[position]["profile_img"],
                                                 fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                               ):Image.asset("assets/person_icon.png"),
                                             ),
                                           )
                                       )),
                                   Positioned(
                                     bottom: 100,
                                     right: 45,
                                     child: InkWell(
                                       onTap: () {},
                                       child:  Center(
                                         child: CircleAvatar(
                                           backgroundColor: colorGreen,
                                           radius: 15.0,
                                           child: Icon(
                                             Icons.check,
                                             color: Colors.white,
                                             size: 25,
                                           ),
                                         ),
                                       ),
                                     ),
                                   ),

                                 ],
                               ),
                             ),
                           ],));
}
```

You can insert more the same way. Don't forget to add an else statement

Comment: Thanks for your comment but your code is not explanatory enough, where is the dummy widget added? How is it connecting with my ```numberofuserleft```